# How to update initialState in redux reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

Hi i update the initial state in reducer by adding new array variable to it but when i console this reducer state it show me the old state and that array is not in the state which is causing the crash when i try to access that array.

```
import {
  USER_SET_LOC,
  USER_SET_FIRST,
} from '../actions/userActions'

const initialState = {
  location: {
    region: 'ABC',
    isDefault: true
  },
  first: [],
  second : []
}

function userReducer (state = initialState, action) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_SET_LOC: {
      return {
        ...state,
        location: {
          ...action.payload,
          isDefault: false
        }
      }
    }
    case USER_SET_FIRST: {
      return {
        ...state,
        first: action.payload
      }
    }
    default:
      return state;
      
  }
}

export default userReducer
```

i added the second array later.
when i console the state in another class i get this

```
{"first": [], "location": {"isDefault": true, "region": "ABC"}}
```

Whatever i change in the initialState it does not appear.
When i uninstall it and reinstall the app then new changes appear

Comment: how are you fetching state in your classes?

Comment: ```
  const  state  = useSelector(state => state.user)
  console.log(state)
```

Comment: It should work, we need more code to see if any issues are there

Comment: It is working. but when i change something in reducer i.e adding new variable to initialState or adding new case, it does'nt update unless i reinstall the app then i get the updated state

Comment: *reinstall the app* means? restarting the server like with "npm start"?

Comment: No uninstall app from phone and then react-native run-android to freshly install the app